# I'm not getting an .exe for my game after building?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D and have been building a zombie survival game for my university course. My issue is after building my game I am not given a `.exe` file.

Some of the things I have already tried:

1. Reinstalling Unity
2. Spoke to my tutor who said I had missed out on some components needed when installing Unity - `UWP Build Support (.NET)` & `UWP Build Support (IL2CPP)`. Reinstalled Unity with these components, still no .exe file.
3. Posted this question on the Unity Community - still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Are you building for the standalone platform or UWP? UWP does not produce or use exe files. You'll get an appex file and a powershell script to install the dependencies and application. Only the standalone platform produces an exe file.

Comment: I built with the standalone platform and the target platform is Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall unity with a different version or to change machine probably there are problems with your set up

Answer (score 1):

Try to build without checking the **Create Visual Studio Solution** checkbox

Answer (score 0):

File > Build Settings… is the menu item to access the Build Settings window
[image]

It’s simply a matter of choosing the build target in the build settings dialog, and hitting the ‘Build’ button. When building standalone players, the resulting files will vary depending on the build target. For the Windows build target, an executable file (.exe) will be built, along with a Data folder which contains all the resources for your application. For the Mac build target, an app bundle will be built which contains the file needed to run the application as well as the resources.

(you may have to complete your options in player settings or probably you missed to select platform)

Comment: what type of file you got after the build?

Comment: I built with the standalone platform and the target platform is Windows. I will have a look over the player settings to see if I missed anything. I definitely didn't forget to select the platform. I get some folders and some c# files.